# Powershell slicing

Tags: powershell, slice

I have a variable like this

```
$sourceid="/subscriptions/9800-565758393-asdjasi134-23123/resourceGroups/KC-EMEA-RSGP-PROJECTS-DEV-01/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/kc-emea-sqsrv-projects-dev-01/databases/KC-EMEA-SQDB-projects-dev-01"
```

I need to create a pwsh script that takes for example the 4th or the 7th field after the slash and store to other variable. Which is the best way?

Comment: `$sourceid -split '/'` maybe?

Comment: Yes. Correct.                                                                                                                   
    $sourceid.Split('/')[5]
    $sourceid.Split('/')[7]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a blank line in the beginning.

```
$fifth,$eighth = ($sourceid -split '/')[5,8]

$fifth
providers

$eighth
kc-emea-sqsrv-projects-dev-01
```